# variable is Null despite receiving data

Tags: c#, linked-list

attempting to insert a node into a Linked-List keeps crashing my Debug as apparently the position of the node I am passing is null and I can't figure out why

```
private void addBefore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxCarName.Text) &&
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxNodePosition.Text)))
        {
            LinkedListNode<string> current = myCarCollection.Find(textBoxNodePosition.Text);
            myCarCollection.AddBefore(current, textBoxCarName.Text);
            showLinkedList();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter both a Car name and a valid Node position");
    }
```

above is the button I click that checks the "TextBoxNodePosition" TextBox and and then attempts to add a node in before the one selected, however when I check the crash notes, "current" is null, yet TextBoxNodePosition has a number to give

edit: screenshot
[image: VS IDE Error]

Comment: It seems to me that `myCarCollection.Find(textBoxNodePosition.Text)` is returning null.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a binary tree, either.

Comment: when I hover it however in the crash, it tells me that, in my current example, "myCarCollection.Find(textBoxNodePosition.Text)" is currently holding a "3" yet the next line has "current" not having been passed that

Comment: `"myCarCollection.Find(textBoxNodePosition.Text)" is currently holding a "3"` - how are you seeing this in the debugger? Are you using the Immediate Window?

Comment: whoops my bad, sorry was doing work on Binary trees earlier, have edited.

Comment: I'm seeing it in the visual studio IDE, that tells me when the Debug has crashed

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of where it shows that value? I don't think hovering over "Find" would show you the result, so only advancing to the line "AddBefore" is on would show you the value assigned to current, which I strongly suspect to be null.

Comment: I've updated the the query with an imgur link to the IDE i'm seeing

Comment: OK, `current` is null, so the existing value isn't found in the list.

Comment: Ahh, so would that mean entries I had already made to the list don't have values in the linked list assigned to them?

Comment: I'm not sure what your setup is, but if I understand you correctly (that you have some separate entity, and then the linked list, and the data is in one but not the other), yes.

Comment: Ahh excellent, thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: The tooltip says " **count=** 3". That means your list contains 3 elements. But it seems the text you are looking for is not one of them. That's why current is null. You should add a null-check and think about what should happen in that case. For example you could simply append the new element.